# How can I disable Microsoft Security Essentials?

Tags: windows-7, anti-virus, ms-security-essentials

Can I disable the Microsoft security essentials in Windows 7 ? How to do it?

Answer (score 2):

open MSE, SETTINGS tab, select REAL-TIME PROTECTION, and uncheck "Turn on real-time protection".

Turn it back on when done.

PS I'm suprised you need to do this as you can ignore files and folders!

Comment: thanks for answer I want to create optical Recovery disc ... and I read that I have to disable any antivirus